# Ошибка версии composer пакета

Tags: composer

Создал свой [пакет](https://packagist.org/packages/mepihindeveloper/php-query-param) и не могу в другом проекте подключить его:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
> Could not find a version of package mepihindeveloper/php-query-param matching your minimum-stability (dev). Require it with an explicit version constraint allowing its desired stability.

Вот сам composer.json нового проекта:

```
{
    "name": "mepihindeveloper/php-query",
    "description": "Component for working with query string",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "MIT",
    "keywords": [
        "component",
        "class",
        "php",
        "query",
        "params",
        "query string"
    ],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "mepihindeveloper",
            "email": "mepihindeveloper@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "mepihindeveloper\\components\\query\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require-dev": {
        "codeception/codeception": "^4.1",
        "codeception/module-phpbrowser": "^1.0.0",
        "codeception/module-asserts": "^1.0.0"
    }
}
```

Подключаю так: `composer require mepihindeveloper/php-query-param`. Версия composer: `Composer version 1.6.3 2018-01-31 16:28:17`.

Другой аналогичный [пакет](https://packagist.org/packages/mepihindeveloper/php-headers) подключается без проблем... Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась временем. На самом деле я немного криво сделал релиз для композера. Надо было сначала выпустить релиз, а только потом в первый раз добавлять его в список пакетов композера.

Через какое-то время, композер сам понял, что есть релизы.